# xticklabels do not appear in figure while plotting with streamlit

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, streamlit

Hello I am trying to plot a dataframe using seaborn in streamlit. The xlabel is a string object with Article number such as '655458', '898555', etc. But when I plot the ylabels are printed correctly but the xlabel just display as 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. I tried searching solutions for this on internet but couldn't find any.
Here is the description of the columns I want to plot:

The x axis

```
x['Artikelnummer'].head()

0    6075150.0
1    6075304.0
2    6075330.0
3    6075355.0
4    6075370.0
Name: Artikelnummer, dtype: object
```

The y axis:

```
y['Presskraft-Gesamt'].head()

0     68.0
1     79.0
2    115.0
3     60.0
4     65.0
Name: Presskraft-Gesamt, dtype: float64
```

When I plot the data using streamlit. I get the following graph.

```
if st.checkbox('Plot data for each Artikeltyp'):
    data_load_state = st.text(f"Plotting data for {artikel_typ}...")
    temp = temp.astype({'Artikelnummer':str})
    
    sns.set_style(style="darkgrid")
        
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,1, sharex=True)
    fig.suptitle(f"Presskraft Auswertung für Artikeltyp - {artikel_typ}")
    
    axes.set_title(f"Gesamt Presskraft")
    sns.lineplot(ax=axes, data=temp, x='Artikelnummer', y='Presskraft-Gesamt')
    
    #print(list(axes.xaxis.get_majorticklabels()))
    axes.set_xticklabels(axes.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=45)
    #plt.setp(axes.get_xticklabels(), visible=False, rotation=25)
    axes.set_ylabel("Presskraft-Gesamt")
    print(list(axes.xaxis.get_majorticklabels()))
    st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True, figsize=(12,8))
```

[image]

It can clearly be seen that the xlabels are not displayed as it should be as per the data in the column.
I would appreciate some suggestions here :) Thank you!

Comment: Can you try setting the xticklabels directly, like `axes.set_xticklabels(temp['Artikelnummer'])`

Comment: @tsj Hi,  I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: @MurtazaBasu  Instead of writing *"it doesn't work"*, you might explain the result you did get.  Anyway, using `set_xticklabels()` without first calling `set_xticks()` often leads to unwanted results.  To rotate the tick labels, the recommended approach is `axes.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=45)`. [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html)